# /usr/bin/find: Argument list too long

Tags: bash

I know this is a common error but I'm really stuck and could use some help.

I need to create an Excel sheet of any files in a subdirectory named `Parent`, that exists in the root folder `Tabletop`. This is what I have:

```
find $(find /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/STUDIO-COMPLETE/ARCHIVE/Tabletop -type d -iname parent | xargs) -type f > Parent_Files_TT.csv
```

It searches for folders named `Parent` and then copies the full file path to Excel. This has worked on other smaller folders I have, but `Tabletop` has hundreds of thousands of files in it and I get the error:

> /usr/bin/find: Argument list too long

I have tried to modify this to use `xargs` when finding the file:

```
find $(find /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/STUDIO-COMPLETE/ARCHIVE/Tabletop -type d -iname parent | xargs) -type f -print0 | xargs > Parent_Files_TT.csv
```

And have also tried `"*"`:

```
find $(find /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/STUDIO-COMPLETE/ARCHIVE/Tabletop -type d -iname parent | xargs) -type f -name "*" > Parent_Files_TT.csv
```

But I'm getting the same error. If someone can help me modify this I'd be really grateful.

Comment: Don't you need to pair `xargs -0` with `find ... -print0`?

Comment: I was really confident that this would work actually, by adding *-type f -print0 | xargs -0*, but unfortunately I still get the same error.

Comment: I think the `find $(...)` part is the problem here. You're interpolating a massive thing. Try restructuring this to pipe the result of the first find into the second somehow.

Answer (score 2):

This part

```
find /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/STUDIO-COMPLETE/ARCHIVE/Tabletop \
    -type d -iname parent
```

returns too many results, and your outer command becomes too long. You can avoid that by nesting your `find`s differently:

```
find /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/STUDIO-COMPLETE/ARCHIVE/Tabletop \
    -type d -iname parent \
    -exec find {} -type f \; > Parent_Files_TT.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than putting a find in your find, just do it in one pass:

```
find /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/STUDIO-COMPLETE/ARCHIVE/Tabletop \
    -ipath '*/parent/*' -type f
```